# ERROR: attempt to invoke virtual method on null object reference

Tags: android-studio

On running my app I get the error which says: attempt to invoke virtual method on null object reference. And according to an error line the method is the setVisibilty method.
The important code is:

> 

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
>     private Button btn;
>         private Button btn1;
>         private Button btn3;
>     
>     
>     
>     tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager){
>                 @Override
>                 public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
>     
>                     switch (tab.getPosition()) {
>                         
>                         case 0:
>                             btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button15);
>     btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>                             break;
>     
>                         case 1:
>                             btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button16);
>                             btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>                             break;
>     
>                         case 2:
>     btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button17);
>                             btn3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>                             break;
>     
>     
>     
>                         }
>                     super.onTabSelected(tab);
>     
>                 }
>             }
>             );
>     }
```

The error method is the setVisibilty method.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What line is it throwing on?

Answer (score 0):

can u be more specific I tried that code working perfectly for me can u be more specific regarding error. here is my working code. **addOnTabSelectedListener()** can be replaced with **setOnTabSelectedListener()** as in ur case.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button btn;
    private Button btn1;
    private Button btn3;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                visibilityChange(tab);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                visibilityChange(tab);
            }
        });
    }

    private void visibilityChange(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        switch (tab.getPosition()) {
            case 0:
                btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                if (btn.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;

            case 1:
                btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
                if (btn1.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;

            case 2:
                btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
                if (btn3.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    btn3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    btn3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```